# Alfresco Plugin Metadata writer Guide

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, alfresco

Can't find any information for how to install/work with Alfresco Plugin "`Metadata writer`".
 Can anybody help me?

What I did:

1. downloaded source from:
   https://github.com/zaizi/alfresco-metadata-writer
2. changed Alfresco version in pom.xml
3. compiled to jar
4. copied metadatawriter-4.2.8.jar to `$ALFRESCO_HOME\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\lib`
5. restart Tomcat

Result: cant find "Metadata Writeable" aspect for documents

I also tried copying jar to `$ALFRESCO_HOME\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\lib` with no luck.

By the way, I use Alfresco Community Edition 5 and Metadata Writer fork (compatible with 5.x).

Comment: What is your Alfresco version you changed to?

Comment: <alfresco.version>5.2.e</alfresco.version>   
 <alfresco.client.war.version>5.2.e</alfresco.client.war.version>

Comment: And I have following information while pressing Alfresco Icon at the bottom:  Alfresco Share v5.2.f
(r137983-b22, Aikau 1.0.101.10, Spring Surf 5.2.f, Spring WebScripts 6.15, Freemarker 2.3.20-alfresco-patched, Rhino 1.7R4-alfresco-patched, Yui 2.9.0-alfresco-20141223)  
Alfresco Community v5.2.0
(re21f2be5-b22) schema 10057

Comment: I have just tried to recompile for 5.2.f version. No changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find this aspect because this module for repo layer only. You can add this aspect in javascript/java web-script only (programmatic way).
If you want to show this aspect in UI you should configure Share part too by yourself.
Go to https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-content-models-tutorials-add-aspect.html and from #3.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can see MetadataWriter aspect and can add it to document. But I dont understand how it should work... I added aspect to some Word document, edited Author, Title and Description. So I expect to see these properties in downloaded file. But looks like something is wrong.

Comment: @DmitryYun I don't know how this is should work. You should research source code to get this out. Maybe your mimetype are not supported. Maybe any other issues (in logs).
When you decided to use this module I suppose you did your homework (how it's works, what mimetypes are supported, what mechanics are used behaviors|rules etc.). 

I just told you, if you what to see this aspect in UI you should configure Share part.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the jar file inside the $ALFRESCO_HOME\tomcat\shared\lib folder?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have just tried. No errors - no MetadataWriter aspect.

Comment: That is the way to use it.
Could you share the startup log for this server?

Comment: Logs: (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FAQXBLAF36Jlliof7E2IzZhNgyDqJrhS)